# Updating operation from sum to subtract or viceversa depending on a given value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to sum or subtract the values of an array.

For example:

`[1, 5, 10]` should be represented as: `1 + 5 + 10 = 16`.

And `[1, 5, -1, 10, 5]` should be: `1 + 5 - 10 - 5` the `-1` number indicates subtraction or sum depending where the `-1` is. The 1st `-1` will indicate subtraction, the second one `-1` indicates that everything is getting back to a regular sum as everything was in the beginning, the 3rd will be subtraction again, and so on.

Now look how it should be with 2 `-1`s: `[1, 5, -1, 10, 5, -1, 5, 5]`, it
should be represented as: `1 + 5 - 10 - 5 + 5 + 5`, got it ?

So, everything should be sum up until the array contains a `-1` so it changes to subraction, if there is another `-1` the operation should change to be a sum. And so on, every time there is a new '-1' the operation changes to the contrary it was before.

I am doing that calculation like this:

```
function calculate (){

    logingValues();
    var total = 0;
    var shouldSubtract = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (arrayOfNumbers[i] === "") continue;
        var currentNumber = parseInt(arrayOfNumbers[i], 10);

        if(isNaN(currentNumber)) {
            currentNumber = 0;
        }

        if (currentNumber === -1) {
            shouldSubtract = true;
        } else {
            if (shouldSubtract) {
                total -= currentNumber;
                shouldSubtract = false;
            } else {
                total += currentNumber;
            }
        }
    }
    caculationEffect(total);
}
```

[And here is the whole code](https://jsbin.com/reliyof/15/edit?js,output)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a variable for the deciding if to add or subtract the actual value.

```js
function sum(array){
    var negative;
    return array.reduce(function (a, b) {
        if (b === -1) {
            negative = !negative;
            return a;
        }
        return negative ? a - b : a + b;
    }, 0);
}

console.log(sum([1, 5, 10]));
console.log(sum([1, 5, -1, 10, 5]));
console.log(sum([1, 5, -1, 10, 5, -1, 5, 5]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my short [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) solution:

```
[1, 5, -1, 10, 5, -1, 5, 5].reduce(function(ctx, x) {
    if (x === -1)                 // if the current value is -1 ...
        ctx.sign *= -1;           // - change the sign
    else                          // otherwise ...
        ctx.sum += x * ctx.sign;  // - transform according to the sign
    return ctx;                   // return context
}, { sign: 1, sum: 0 }).sum;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but first I am trying to understand how to adapt it to my code. It looks complicated.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer I have modified it to even more simple variant. This doesn't use any `eval` and is always safe to use. Added comments to make it more clear.

Comment: I am doing it now but I am getting an error: https://jsbin.com/reliyof/16/edit?js,console,output. `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.`

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Everything is correct. You simply just need to assign the result to your `total` variable: `var total = arrayOfNumbers.reduce(...).sum;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one `var` and change `true/false` each time element in array is `-1`

```js
function sum(a) {
  var check = true, result = 0;
  a.forEach(function(e) {
    
    //If e is negative number and check is true change check to false
    if (e < 0 && check == true) {
      check = false;
    //If e is negative number and check is false change check to true
    } else if (e < 0 && check == false) {
      check = true;
    }
   
    //If e is positive number and check is true add to result
    if (e > 0 && check == true) {
      result += e;
    //If e is positive number and check is false subtract of result
    } else if (e > 0 && check == false) {
      result -= e;
    }
  })
  return result;
}

console.log(sum([1, 5, 10]));
console.log(sum([1, 5, -1, 10, 5]));
console.log(sum([1, 5, -1, 10, 5, -1, 5, 5]));
```

Answer (score 1):

To add another to the mix, not because it's better, but because it's possible :) (although this version does depend on ES6 )

```js
function calc(arr){
    var [v,...rest] = arr; //assign v to the first value, rest to the following values        
    var sr = rest.length ? calc(rest) : 0; //calc sum of rest
    return v === -1 ? -sr : v + sr; //if value === -1, return sum of rest with reversed sign, otherwise return sum
}

console.log(calc([1, 5, 10]));
console.log(calc([1, 5, -1, 10, 5]));
console.log(calc([1, 5, -1, 10, 5, -1, 5, 5]));
```